# Is it possible to set interface name permanently in Raspbian?

Tags: linux, networking, udev, network-interface

I'm using 2 wifi dongles. First one is used to monitor and second one is used to access internet. Even if I changed `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` as below, at startup sometimes `wlan0` cannot be assigned. Since `wlan1` is used for another device, `wlan0` is renamed as `rename3`. I'm using `wlan0` for specific purpose and I'm giving its interface name to another program. How can I set `wlan0` permanently so my other programs that are using `wlan0` can keep on functioning?

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="AA-12-00-00-2B-8B", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="e8:4e:06:24:c2:df", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan1"
```

Comment: Can you try to name them something that doesn't conflict with kernel names, like `wifi0` and `wifi1`, and see if that works?

Answer (score 0):

`ATTR{address}=="AA-12-00-00-2B-8B"` is not a valid MAC address (replace the - with dots and uppercase with lowercase letters), so the first rule will never match. Fix this and they should work reliably.

Anyway, on modern systems (like current RHEL and the next Debian and Ubuntu releases) you cannot rename an interface to a name in one of the kernel namespaces (in this case `wlan*`), so you should rename the interfaces to different names like e.g. `wl0`.